# Getting different results for same operation in windows 10 and virtual machine Ubuntu

Tags: python, numpy

I am adding 1 to some elements of a numpy array. In Win 10, everything works fine. 
But in Ubuntu running on virtual machine as a guest OS, the program generates huge numbers that are impossible to be the result of my code. For example, in Linux instead of "11" which is a correct result, it will produce something like this: 4846223038150164788" !!!!

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Here is the part of the code:

```
Import numpy as np
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = [1, 3, 1, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 5]
counter = np.ndarray(shape = (len(A),10) , dtype = np.int64)
for k in B:
    x = np.int64(1)
    if k == int(word[0]):
        counter[n][D[k][0]] += x
```

I want to test my code to see whether it is working properly on Linux or not.
If the VM is the problem, is there any other way that I can test my code and see the results?

Comment: What are `A` and `B`?

Comment: They are 2 lists . I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `numpy.ndarray()` to create new NumPy arrays. This is because NumPy will *allocate* the data for the array, but not initialize the values, meaning they'll get the data that happens to have been in the newly-allocated memory (when memory is deallocated, it isn't reset, the references to it are simply removed).

You can see this in action if you look any array created by `numpy.ndarray()` without any further modification:

```
>>> numpy.ndarray((5,))
array([2.68156159e+154, 2.68156159e+154, nan, 0.00000000e+000, 2.68156159e+154])
```

I'm not sure why this isn't a problem on  Windows too. Possibly, Windows initializes newly-allocated memory. It might also be that your Linux VM has less memory available to it and is therefore more likely to reuse memory than your Windows host, which has more memory and is therefore more likely to give you "fresh" (not previously used) memory on allocation. I've saw a  bug one that assume initialized memory, and it would only show up reliably on low-memory machines.

At any rate, change you initialization to:

```
counter = np.zeros((len(A),10), dtype=np.int64)
```

And it should solve your issue.

From the docs:

> Arrays should be constructed using array, zeros or empty (refer to the See Also section below). The parameters given here refer to a low-level method (ndarray(…)) for instantiating an array.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html?highlight=ndarray#numpy.ndarray

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have changed it, and it's working properly.